# How to determine which instance of an operator is being called?

Tags: python, python-2.7, operators

I have a class called `MyData` that has `__mul__` and `__rmul__` defined (along with all the other arithmetic operators).  Whenever these methods are used, it should always return a value of type `MyData`.  However, I discovered that `a * myDataObj` is not the same as `myDataObj * a`, depending on the type of `a`.  Specifically, if `a` was an `int`, it worked fine, but if `a` was a `float` then the first configuration return an array (my object has a numpy array as a member, and `MyData.__getitem__` returns slices of that array) and the second configuration returns the proper value of type `MyData`.

Is there any way to determine the calling order of the operator in an expression like this?

Comment: If you want us to debug your code for you, rather than just explaining the principles, you will need to show us your actual code—or, better, a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to determine the calling order of the operator in an expression like this?

First, the exact rules are described in the [Data model](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) section of the language reference, specifically the "Emulating numeric types" subsection.

The `__rfoo__` methods are described as follows:

> These methods are called to implement the binary arithmetic operations (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `divmod()`, `pow()`, `**`, `<<`, `>>`, `&`, `^`, `|`) with reflected (swapped) operands. These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of different types. [2] For instance, to evaluate the expression `x - y`, where `y` is an instance of a class that has an `__rsub__()` method, `y.__rsub__(x)` is called if `x.__sub__(y)` returns `NotImplemented`.
>
> Note that ternary `pow()` will not try calling `__rpow__()` (the coercion rules would become too complicated).
>
> Note If the right operand’s type is a subclass of the left operand’s type and that subclass provides the reflected method for the operation, this method will be called before the left operand’s non-reflected method. This behavior allows subclasses to override their ancestors’ operations.

Putting this into Pythonesque pseudocode, `x * y` is evaluated something like this:

```
if type(y) is type(x):
    return x.__mul__(y)
elif type(y) is a subclass of type(x):
    try y.__rmul__(x)
    otherwise x.__mul__(y)
else:
    try x.__mul__(y)
    otherwise y.__rmul__(x)
```

Of course you can also determine the calling order dynamically by creating separate types whose methods just print their names and testing them:

```
class Base(object):
    def __mul__(self, lhs): print('Base.mul')
    def __rmul__(self, rhs): print('Base.rmul')

class Derived(Base):
    def __mul__(self, lhs): print('Derived.mul')
    def __rmul__(self, rhs): print('Derived.rmul')

class Unrelated(object):
    def __mul__(self, lhs): print('Unrelated.mul')
    def __rmul__(self, rhs): print('Unrelated.rmul')

print('Base * Base: ', end='')
Base() * Base()
for x, y in itertools.permutations((Base, Derived, Unrelated), 2):
    print('{} * {}: '.format(x.__name__, y.__name__), end='')
    x() * y()
```

---

> What about with built in types as well?

Exactly the same rules. Since `Base` is not a subclass of either `int` or `float`, and neither `int` nor `float` knows how to multiply by it, they'll both call `Base.__rmul__`. And so will any other unrelated type you throw at it:

```
>>> Base() * 2
Base.mul
>>> 2 * Base()
Base.rmul
>>> Base() * 2.5
Base.mul
>>> 2.5 * Base()
Base.rmul
>>> 'sdfsdfsdfds' * Base()
Base.rmul
>>> (lambda: 23) * Base()
Base.rmul
```

> My problem is that I'm getting different results from 1.5 * myObj and myObj * 1.5

There are a number of reasons for that:

- Your `__mul__` and `__rmul__` code don't do the same thing.
- You inherited from `float`.
- You inherited from some builtin or extension type that handles float multiplication at the C-API level and isn't designed to allow overrides in subclasses.
- You created a classic class instead of a new-style class.
- You made a typo in one of the names.
- …

Comment: What about with built in types as well?  My problem is that I'm getting different results from `1.5 * myObj` and `myObj * 1.5`, even though `__mul__` and `__rmul__` are defined for my type.

Comment: @bheklilr: Unless you're using classic classes, the rules are exactly the same for built-in types. (Including the inheritance rules, so if you inherit from `int`, you will of course get different behavior for `int` and `float`.) Let me edit the answer to show you.

Comment: One thing I should mention, to address the comment that someone added and then removed: This all applies to classes implemented in Python, which is what the OP was clearly interested in. But if a future reader is writing extension classes in C (or Cython), they have different rules, so this answer does not apply.

Comment: And what does apply for extension classes?